# how can I configure MSSQL 2019 on a Failover Cluster without an AD domain? What service account to use?

Tags: sql-server, clustering

I am working on testing a particular software issue that requires the use of a MS SQL installation on a Windows Failover Cluster.

For various reasons I can't use an AD Domain for this particular testing, so I have set up the Windows Failover Clustering without that, and it is working fine.

The problem comes when I go to install MSSQL 2019 and it asks me which accounts to use for the SQL Server Agent and SQL Server Database Engine.

Nothing works -- NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE doesn't work, nor does NT SERVICE\MSSQLLFDLauncher, nor does the built-in Administrator, nor does the cluster admin (clustadm) account I have created on both nodes.

> The credentials you provided for the SQL Server Agent service are invalid. To continue, provide a valid account and password for the SQL Server Agent service.

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Configuration.Agent.InputValidationException: The credentials you provided for the SQL Server Agent service are invalid. To continue, provide a valid account and password for the SQL Server Agent service.

It keeps asking me for a Domain Account but that isn't an option here.  Is there some workaround?

Comment: Are you installing an FCI or an AG? You must be domain joined to use an FCI but you don't need to be for an AG.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. I'm afraid Always On Availability Groups are supported on workgroup.
See post from Edwin M Sarmiento (Microsoft Certified Master/Solutions Master)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3ba18080-2ab8-4444-bd17-74a39f4202a0/unable-to-install-sql-cluster-in-workgroup?forum=sqldisasterrecovery

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers as links do go dead over time.